# Upgrade gitlab runner from 9 to 10

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I would like to upgrade my gitlab runner from version 9 to 10: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#updating-the-runner

But when running `sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner`, the process is switching to the old multi runner.

I already tried to remove the old runner:

```
sudo apt-get remove gitlab-ci-multi-runner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to update repository configuration as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/linux-repository.html#installing-the-runner):

```
# For Debian/Ubuntu
curl -L https://packages.gitlab.com/install/repositories/runner/gitlab-runner/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
```

Then you can install new version of runner with

```
sudo apt-get install gitlab-runner
```

It will remove previous package automatically.